# Angular - fxFlex has no effect on elements

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

This question is related to Angular 2+ and the @angular/flex-layout package.

When trying to use `fxFlex="30"` for example, CSS styles are not being applied to elements.

```
<mat-toolbar fxFlex="30" color="primary">
    <h2>Uh-oh</h2>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you import the module in `app.module.ts` like so:

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
```

and also add it to imports in `@NgModule`.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on exactly the same problem when I found your question...

It's actually answered on the Angular Material website: https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/overview#positioning-toolbar-content

The problem is that fxFlex is not working on mat-toolbar. If you change your mat-toolbar to a div then fxFlex will work fine. But if you need to use mat-toolbar then you need to manually style the containers within the toolbar to make the flex work. Just using fxFlex, in the way you normally do, won't work on mat-toolbar.

Here's my working example for a full width toolbar with a logo on the left and some buttons on the right:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">

  <span>
    put the left content here, for example your logo
  </span>

  <span fxFlex style="flex: 1 1 auto;"></span>

  <span>
    put the right content here, for example a button
  </span>

</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I only missed the `import` bit. after that it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior can occur if you forget to import and declare a component using fxflex in its module.

So if you have a component "home" you must remember in your app.module.ts (or child module)

```
...
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      NavbarComponent,
      HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
...
```